# Changing docker root is not registerd by mesosphere dcos

Tags: docker, config, centos7, mesosphere, dcos

By adding `"graph": "/dcos/docker/"` to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` , I changed the docker root dir for all my Mesosphere DCOS agnet-nodes to run under a larger disk instead of the root(/) volume.

Through `docker info`, I saw change from `Docker Root Dir:/var/lib/docker/`
to `Docker Root Dir:/dcos/docker/`.

Then from what i can see the change worked with Docker, since all volumes and all container are created in the directory of `/dcos/docker`. But the problem is that Mesosphere DCOS do not seem to notice such a  change. When launching containers from the GUI or CLI, it can not start containers that needs a persistent volume larger than the size of root(/) even if the docker root volume is much larger.

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root  150G  4.3G  146G   3% /
/dev/sda1                881G  3.8G  832G   1% /dcos/docker
```

But as soon as i start a container that only needs a smaller size than the root disk, it works and places it under the /dcos/docker.

**Is there any way to make Mesosphere DCOS recalculating the free space it can use for persistent storage? or make the agent-node to notice that the docker root dir is not under root(/) volume anymore?**

In the gui, when asking looking at the debug "Recent Resource Offers" table, i can see that the node offerd 1T of storage but the task request 0 bytes and a red X  on the disk paramter. But on other agent-nodes with larger roots than requested size, it is a green checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by changing the mount location of the disk from `/dcos/docker` to `/var` and changed back the location of docker root to `/var/lib/docker`. This fixed both root from filling up by docker containers and allows me to allocate larger presentient volumes in dcos.

```
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root    50G   12G   39G  24% /
devtmpfs                  148G     0  148G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     148G     0  148G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     148G  250M  148G   1% /run
tmpfs                     148G     0  148G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                1014M  184M  831M  19% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-lvol1  2.0T   39M  2.0T   1% /dcos/volume0
/dev/mapper/centos-lvol0  4.0T   17G  4.0T   1% /var
/dev/mapper/centos-lvol2  1.8T   33M  1.8T   1% /dcos/volume1
overlay                   4.0T   17G  4.0T   1% /var/lib/docker/overlay/095f55a30c322914b0d4b82ac90a884fd5a1b1f937ce94654bf961e59644f720/merged
shm                        64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e73e8277e9ce4270afd38038ecc2116e3a12e415783a611a74a7900f6241fe3a/shm
overlay                   4.0T   17G  4.0T   1% /var/lib/docker/overlay/19c8656cf344a3dce3cbce73040961af551d38bb4f63843dd173d075c72ba58b/merged
shm                        64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/ccfcd9707003e55d229884ac283b977df634ae9d5c8b5f04517dba94c255fa5d/shm
overlay                   4.0T   17G  4.0T   1% /var/lib/docker/overlay/886b3e427b2c2d8ff2854e015bd91617253c069fdf9537a882dac10584720924/merged
shm                        64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/654b4a4bd9aaa13720fbe3be81f48228d35932a45f5af56789c9fdd4b974294b/shm
tmpfs                      30G     0   30G   0% /run/user/0
```